# Python through command terminal, creating functions?

Tags: command-line, python, idle-python

I am new to Ubuntu. I formerly used to use python on windows, and now I am learning Ubuntu. When I open the command terminal, I type python and press Enter,the symbol (>>>) is shown and I am in IDLE. However, I want to know how I can create functions and classes and the stuff I used to to in Windows.

Thanks.

Comment: What were you using in Windows as a Python shell? If that's also IDLE, then there's no difference in Ubuntu. However, I think you should check out iPython if you find the time. It's a lot more powerful than IDLE.

Comment: The difference is: in windows you can go to file-->new module and create what you want

Answer (score 7):

Creating functions using the CLI is very similar to creating functions in scripts. Type your function name and arguments on the first line and append a colon. After that the Pyhton interpreter asks for further input. Now you have to indent the next code you want write in the function body. You finish the function the a blank line.

It should look like:

```
>>> def fun(a,b):
...     print a,b
... 
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

> The difference is: in windows you can go to file-->new module and create what you want

I think what you mean is, that in Windows you're used to the IDLE *GUI*. In Ubuntu you'll have to install the necessary packages in order to run the Tkinter version of IDLE.

Installing the [`idle` [image: Install idle]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/idle) package will make sure you have all the necessary software to run the GUI.

Then run it:

```
idle
```

And it's also in your regular applications list.